# Unexpected margin in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to fill a ListView with icons and text (.View = View.LargeIcons)

This is the code I use for testing:

```
        this.LargeImageList = new ImageList();
        this.LargeImageList.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(64, 64);

        this.LargeImageList.Images.Add(Program.ImgImportEntity);
        this.Items.Add("Add 3D Model", 0);
        this.Items.Add("Add 3D Model", 0);
        this.Items.Add("Add 3D Model", 0);
        this.Items.Add("Add 3D Model", 0);
        this.Items.Add("Add 3D Model", 0);
        this.Items.Add("Add 3D Model", 0);
        this.Items.Add("Add 3D Model", 0);
```

And this is the result I'm getting:

[image: Listfiew]

As you can see, there is a margin above the first picture

1 question: Why? All margins are set to 0. Thanks for insights!

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I made a mistake, there was an item defined via the Item Collection editor within VS itself.

Comment: Then you should delete question and 'answer'!